# Use pytz to convert pandas dataframe column with timestamps from UTC to local timezone?

Tags: python, pandas, timezone, pytz

I have a table with time-stamped data, like this:

[image]

How do I convert the entire TimeStamp column from UTC to local time with the pytz module? Input is an IANA formatted timezone, like eg. "Europe/London". The table is stored in a pandas dataframe.

Comment: what is the original format of the table, Excel? and you load that into a pandas df? what is the dtype of your column 'TimeStamp'?

Comment: @MrFuppes The original format is a Microsoft Power BI table, which is generated with an SQL query to a database. The datatype of the TImeStamp column is Microsoft DateTime / DateTimeZone. Under the hood, Power BI and Excel are very similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need the pytz module ? You can use `tz` info within the pandas.

for eg. something like this can be done:

```
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('Europe/London')
```

You may want to check more detail here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.tz_convert.html

Comment: the timestamps on the OP's screenshot should already be casted to UTC if read by pd.to_datetime; something like `df['local_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TimeStamp']).dt.tz_convert('Europe/London')` should do.

Comment: This really looks like it should work, but I get a long list of error messages. I am not very experienced with pandas and am unsure what to learn from it. It looks like I first need to convert the TimeStamp format which is currently the microsoft datetime format.

DataSource.Error: ADO.NET: Python script error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
ValueError: Array must be all same time zone

Comment: @MrFuppes Your solution works really well, thank you.